# Cannot get quandl to proceed after encountering BRK.B in retrieving ticker symbols from WIkipedia

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quandl

I am fairly new to python and this code basically returns Ticker Data from the wiki page of 'List of S&P 500 companies'. I have tried replacing the '.' with '_' but I continuously encounter the error:

> AssertionError: Symbol 'BRK_B' must conform to **Quandl** convention
>   'DB/SYM

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'Token KEY'
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open('sp500tickers.pickle','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers,f)
    print(tickers)
    return tickers

def get_data_quandl(reload_sp500=False):    
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open ('sp500tickers.pickle','rb') as f:        
            tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

start = dt.datetime(2001,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = web.DataReader(ticker.replace('.', '_'), 'quandl', start, end)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print('Already Have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_quandl()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the ticker in the following format?

'BRK-B'

I know it's not Quandl, but I got this working using the python YahooFinancials module (which is also free by the way):
https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials

```
>>> from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
>>> import json
>>> yf = YahooFinancials('BRK-B')
>>> print(json.dumps(yf.get_historical_price_data("2018-08-01", "2018-08-10", "daily"), indent=4))
```

Which returned:

```
{
    "BRK-B": {
        "eventsData": {}, 
        "firstTradeDate": {
            "date": 831628800, 
            "formatted_date": "1996-05-09"
        }, 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "prices": [
            {
                "high": 199.6999969482422, 
                "volume": 4004600, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-01", 
                "low": 197.32000732421875, 
                "adjclose": 197.85000610351562, 
                "date": 1533130200, 
                "close": 197.85000610351562, 
                "open": 198.8000030517578
            }, 
            {
                "high": 198.75999450683594, 
                "volume": 3269900, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-02", 
                "low": 196.77000427246094, 
                "adjclose": 198.05999755859375, 
                "date": 1533216600, 
                "close": 198.05999755859375, 
                "open": 197.1999969482422
            }, 
            {
                "high": 200.4199981689453, 
                "volume": 5028000, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-03", 
                "low": 198.1199951171875, 
                "adjclose": 200.24000549316406, 
                "date": 1533303000, 
                "close": 200.24000549316406, 
                "open": 198.5
            }, 
            {
                "high": 208.11000061035156, 
                "volume": 6673100, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-06", 
                "low": 204.6199951171875, 
                "adjclose": 206.05999755859375, 
                "date": 1533562200, 
                "close": 206.05999755859375, 
                "open": 204.88999938964844
            }, 
            {
                "high": 209.94000244140625, 
                "volume": 6160100, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-07", 
                "low": 207.14999389648438, 
                "adjclose": 208.72000122070312, 
                "date": 1533648600, 
                "close": 208.72000122070312, 
                "open": 207.5
            }, 
            {
                "high": 209.7100067138672, 
                "volume": 3869000, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-08", 
                "low": 208.42999267578125, 
                "adjclose": 208.94000244140625, 
                "date": 1533735000, 
                "close": 208.94000244140625, 
                "open": 208.80999755859375
            }, 
            {
                "high": 209.64999389648438, 
                "volume": 4684700, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-09", 
                "low": 208.72000122070312, 
                "adjclose": 209.10000610351562, 
                "date": 1533821400, 
                "close": 209.10000610351562, 
                "open": 209.0
            }, 
            {
                "high": 207.77000427246094, 
                "volume": 4383100, 
                "formatted_date": "2018-08-10", 
                "low": 205.58999633789062, 
                "adjclose": 206.6300048828125, 
                "date": 1533907800, 
                "close": 206.6300048828125, 
                "open": 207.3000030517578
            }
        ], 
        "timeZone": {
            "gmtOffset": -14400
        }, 
        "instrumentType": "EQUITY"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not only BRK-B you're going to have an issue with. There are a handful of tickers in the S&P 500 that have hyphens.

The work around, if you insist on using Quandl (Yahoo Finance & Google are both deprecated), is to catch all tickers with a hyphen and format the symbol to conform with Quandl's format. However, this will still throw an error using pandas_datareader QuandlReader. You need to send a get request for all tickers that have to be formatted from a '-' to a '_', like this:

```
    if '-' in s:
        s = s.replace('-', '_')

        with open (f'spoos/{s}.csv', 'w') as f:
            print(s)
            f.write(requests.get(f'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/{s}.csv?start_date={self.start}&end_date={self.end}&order=asc&api_key={apikey}').text)

    if not os.path.exists(f'spoos/{s}.csv'):
        print(s)
        df = web.QuandlReader(s, self.start, self.end, api_key='{apikey}').read()
        df.to_csv(f'spoos/{s}.csv')
```